# Inserting Array of String to Priority Queue C#

Tags: c#, priority-queue

i'm trying to insert array of String to priority queue in c#. Since priority queue is not available in c#, i used [C5 generic Collection Library](http://www.itu.dk/research/c5/) and used its IntervalHeap which extends IPriorityQueue. The problem is IntervalHeap comparable can't sort string of array, my String Array contains 3 item (kind of array for **Uniform Cost Search Algorithm**) which the first and second item is letter, and the third item is Number (trying to sort using this item). So i'm trying to override the comparable library since i can't even add my String Array inside the IntervalHeap.
I know that i can sort object using Arraylist such :

```
List<Foo> data = ...
// sort by name descending
data.Sort((x,y) => -x.Name.CompareTo(y.Name));
```

but i prefer to use it on priority queue

any way on how and what should i add to the overrided comparable?

Example of code :

```
IPriorityQueue<String[]> solution2 = new IntervalHeap<String[]>();
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            String[] test = new String[3];
            test[0] = "aa";
            test[1] = "bb";
            test[2] = i.ToString();
            **solution2.Add(test);** i got an error on this one
        }
        Console.Write(solution2);
```

**EDIT 1**

i did change my code and none of the error comes, instead it doesn't sorted as i want

i made a class :

```
class Way : IComparable
{
    private Char start;

    public Char Start
    {
        get { return start; }
        set { start = value; }
    }

    private Char destination;

    public Char Destination
    {
        get { return destination; }
        set { destination = value; }
    }

    private int distance;

    public int Distance
    {
        get { return distance; }
        set { distance = value; }
    }

    public Way(char start, char destination, int distance)
    {
        Start = start;
        Destination = destination;
        Distance = distance;
    }

    public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null) return 1;

        Way otherway = obj as Way;
        if (otherway != null)
            return this.Distance.CompareTo(otherway.Distance);
        else
            throw new ArgumentException("Object is not a Distance");
    }
}
```

and i print the code :

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            Way a = new Way('a', 'b', i);
            solution2.Add(a);
        }

        foreach (Way item in solution2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Distance);
        }
```

it turns out :
0
7
1
6
3
4
2
5

it's not sorting, any mistakes i did?

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: I suspect you are confusing arrays and Tuples. What kind of comparison would make sense between two arbitrary arrays? Why don't you create a class for this?

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos , i'm trying to compare with the 3rd index of the arrays (which contains number). can't i do that on c# sir? i know that the example of Arraylist on the top is class

Comment: @Ian Additional information: At least one object must implement IComparable.

Comment: Using an array of arbitrary values is not a good idea. For example, "12" is *less* than "3" in string comparisons. If you insist though, the `IntervalHeap(SCG.IComparer<T> comparer, MemoryType memoryType = MemoryType.Normal) ` constructor accepts a comparer instance. Create a class that implements this interface. Of course, it would be a *lot* easier to create a class and use properties eg `int Priorty{get;set;}` instead of weakly typed strings

Comment: i'm trying it but the result is not sorting correctly @Panagiotis Kanavos